# Using jQuery, selecting the next <select> box and change its value

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Based on the title, I am able to do everything except select the correct  box.

The page layout is basically several links (class="class") with a select box next (there are some elements in between the select box and the link) to each link (class="games"). I am trying to change the value ONLY of the select box immediately next to the link being clicked.

*** EDIT ***

here's a fiddle with a better example of the HTML I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/ynSeZ/9/

--- i have tried all of the answers suggested and none have worked. thanks for all the effort so far ! ---

this is what i have so far.. when i remove the closest() part, it works.. but it changes the value of every select box instead of only the way closest to the link.

thanks in advance,
phil

Comment: can you show the html layout. and maybe put an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Neal hope this helps - http://jsfiddle.net/ynSeZ/

Comment: what you want, still unclear, please write the desired output clearly

Comment: mmm i'm not clear . please explain a bit more,

Comment: @Neal - i updated the fiddle so hopefully show a bit better what I'm trying to accomplish. thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @user. organize the html better in the fiddle, its hard to read...

Comment: @Neal - http://jsfiddle.net/ynSeZ/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer. Use `siblings` instead of `closest`:

```
$('.class').click(function() {

    var objectID = $(this).attr('objectID');

    $($(this).siblings('.games').get(0)).val(objectID).attr('selected', true);

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ynSeZ/3/

Now that I think about it, the above answer may be incorrect. You have to implement something to get the closest `select` element. What the above code does is get the first select element on the page, not necessarily the one closest to the `a` tag

---

**UPDATE**

Here is an answer based off your newest fiddle:

```
$('.pick_team').click(function() {

    var objectID = $(this).attr('team_id');

    var select_object = $('select', $(this).parent().parent());

    select_object.val(objectID)
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ynSeZ/12/

Comment: Augh...I *knew* there was a selector that did that; but I couldn't, for the life of me, remember the name...sigh. Have a hearty **+1**! :)

Comment: @user628 no problem, just for next time supply the html fully so we can see the problem outright :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should change your HTML so that the link that gets clicked has only one "sibling" select element. Like this:

```
...
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="class" ... >Value 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="class" ... >Value 2</a>
    <select>
        <option>Foo</option>
        ...
    </select>
</div>
```

Then do this in your Javascript to get the right select element:

```
$(this).sibling("select")
```

where `this` is the link that was clicked.

The `closest` function is kind of misleading. It finds the closest ancestor of the element that matches the given selector.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

**UPDATED** 
This will grab the select box in the same row and set the value as the team_id of the clicked link

```
$('.pick_team').click(function() {
     var val = $(this).attr('team_id'); // grab the team id - we'll use this to determine the selected option in the select box
    //alert(val); // debugging
    $(this).closest('tr').find('select option[value="'+val+'"]').attr("selected","selected");

});
```

Comment: @Neal, it would seem so , my bad

Answer (score 0):

Time for a good, old-fashioned `while` loop:

```
$('.class').click(function() {
    $next = $(this).next();

    while ($next.prop('tagName') !== 'SELECT' && $next.size() > 0)
    {
        $next = $next.next();
    }

    if ($next.prop('tagName') === 'SELECT')
    {
        $next.val($(this).attr('objectID'));
    }
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cM4B5/3/

Edit: Slight typo in the jsFiddle prevented the second link from working. Updated.